# При адаптации разрешений под Android в Unity (С#) объекты уменьшаются

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image][image]Я делаю 2D игру для Android. При адаптации разрешений в Unity (С#) объекты уменьшаются, хотя я их и пытался через RectTransform прикрепить, но размеры маленькие становятся, когда я смотрю на других разрешениях, а делаю я игру в соотношении сторон 9:16. Я прикреплял к Panel все объекты. Как сделать так, чтобы они увеличивались в соответствии со сменой разрешения? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Как именно Вы пытались через RectTransform? При помощи Anchors? Приведите скриншоты при разных разрешениях и пример Вашей настройки RectTransform.

Comment: Вот, можете взглянуть.

Comment: А в Canvas компонент "Canvas Scaler" добавили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен компонент [CanvasScaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html). Он изменяет скейл всех вложенных объектов исходя из выбранной в нём логики. Вешается он автоматически на Canvas верхнего уровня. Там можно выбрать, например, режим  `Scale With Screen Size` в этом случае весь UI вы будете настраивать для конкретного разрешения, а уже скейлер будет менять скейл в зависимости от реального разрешения и заданных параметров.